# cannot access class IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, access, java

Здравствуйте все, такая есть проблема:

IntelliJ IDEA подсвечивает красным (cannot access) this поле в конструкторе, в то время, как при компиляции все работает нормально.

Переустанавливал IDEA, JDK, OS, все бестолку. Уже руки опускаются.
[Ссылка](https://ibb.co/dpaVSa) на скриншот.

Настройки стандартные, IDE тоже. Раньше такого не было.

Comment: Переустанови плагин "JavaRush". Кажись там обновление вышло.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать "Invalidate caches" в IDEA.

Comment: Invalidate просто — не помогло, Invalidate & Restart помог